# Modifying image in Active Storage cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-5, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

I'm using Rails 5.2 and GCS as cloud service.
I'd like to give an opportunity to users to crop and rotate user's image.
User has many Images, Image has one `:image_file` attached

In development I use such method:

```
class Image

...

  def  rotate(degree)
    image =  MiniMagick::Image.new(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, self.image_file.key))
    image.rotate "#{degree}"
    image.write(ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, self.image_file.key))
    self.image_file.blob.analyze
  end

...

end
```

But I can't figure out how to get to image files in cloud.

I've made it to download the file to local storage and  make all the operations needed.

Now  it takes only to replace (delete current and create a new one with the same name) the file in the cloud (without changing anything in the database records if possible), but  I can't figure out how to do this with active storage.

At least I need to get the ***file name in the cloud*** to use just bare `google-cloud-ruby`

Answer (score 0):

To list files stored in Cloud Storage bucket using Ruby on Rails see the code example defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-ruby). You can also [upload files](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage#uploading_to_cloud_storage) to cloud storage bucket and [delete files](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage#deleting_images) from them using Ruby on Rails.

Also since you are allowing your customers to modify their files in Cloud Storage buckets, you may consider using [versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning). This will incur you additional cost but will provide reliability for your customers.

Here is the link to [Ruby on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/) documentation which might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, but listing all the images is unappropriate, because of the amount and because there're images from different users with different privacy settings.

Comment: In my answer I have shared listing, uploading and delete sample code links. In the link you will also find sample code for replacing image.